# Upload files through PHP not working

Tags: php

I am trying to upload a file using a PHP form. I have looked through the solutions suggested here but I still can't get it to work.

My html form is

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="customer_details.php" method="POST">
                                <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="512000" />
                                Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
                                <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
                            </form>
```

and then my PHP part

```
$uploaddir = 'temp_files/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
    $tmp_file = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
    echo 'Tmp file is: ' . $tmp_file;
    echo "<p>";

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
      echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
    } else {
       echo "Upload failed";
    }
    //die();
    echo "</p>";
    echo '<pre>';
    echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
    print_r($_FILES);
    print "</pre>";
```

The results that I am getting from the debugging info are as follows:

```
[userfile] => Array
        (
            [name] => EasyCount Template (1).xlsx
            [type] => application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpcfn8tp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 10012
        )
```

I have created the tmp folder in all possible locations I can think off, yet I still can't figure out what is stopping the file from being uploaded. I've been trying to find the problem for a while now but I just can't see it. The customer_details.php is in a platformDev folder on the server, I have created a tmp folder in here as well.

Comment: So upload is working (we can see that in the debug), the problem is moving it?

Comment: No, I get "Upload failed" echo as well so it looks like even the upload is not working. I have file_uploads = On in php.ini file

Comment: your `'name'` value will cause issues on certain servers which will not enjoy a space character in a file name

Comment: What does your PHP error log say?

Comment: Problem solved by easiest solution ever - folder permissions...

Comment: @artlemaks That's an error message you wrote, and it's wrong because the upload happened fine. Like I said it's the move that's failing. What's the value of `$uploadfile`?

Comment: please also add validations to this. At the moment, trojans and other harmful files can easily be uploaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved... Tip for anyone else coming across this problem in the future - Check your folder permissions and make sure you can write to them...